# QT: No rule to make target 'res/resources.qrc'

Tags: qt, qt5

I've switched versions of QT (from 5.10.1 to 5.12.2) to get a more recent version of Mingw32 (from GCC/G++ 5.3 -> 7.3). The reasoning behind this is that have multiple products using the same library and using an old version of gcc is less than ideal. We've never had any issues with build before, but now I get the following error:

":-1: error: No rule to make target 'res/resources.qrc', needed by 'release/qrc_resources.cpp'.  Stop."

Oddly enough, it does not stop the build from generating a completely functioning executable.

So far I've tried:
Cleaning the directory and building again
Deleting the build directory and building again
Not selecting shadow build option
Forcing Qmake (Build -> Run Qmake)
Creating a new .pro.user file
Deleting the whole repo, cloning it again, rebuilding the dependencies (we have a library which it relies on) and rebuilding QT
Adding the .qrc file to the includes (I know this was silly, but I was at my wits end)
Checking for deleted files (None that I can see)
Checking file names for inconsistencies(They seem ok)

Here is my qrc file

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>images/cnctbtn_connected.png</file>
        <file>images/cnctbtn_connecting.png</file>
        <file>images/cnctbtn_disconnected.png</file>
        <file>images/configbtn.png</file>
        <file>images/flash.png</file>
        <file>images/logbtn.png</file>
        <file>images/streambtn_start.png</file>
        <file>images/streambtn_stop.png</file>
        <file>images/d_logo_outlined.ico</file>
        <file>images/d_logo_small.png</file>
        <file>images/d_logo_small_outlined.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

The list of resources which are located in the images folder

```
cnctbtn_connected.png
cnctbtn_connecting.png
cnctbtn_disconnected.png
configbtn.png
d_logo_small.png
d_logo_small_outlined.png
flash.png
logbtn.png
streambtn_start.png
streambtn_stop.png
d_logo_outlined.ico
```

The qrc_resource_File.cpp also looks ok. I see the bytes of the images in it, their names and assorted namespace declarations and functions in that name space.

The one thing I'm unsure of is why the images folder has it's on name in the resource name list.

Note: I've removed the bytes in this array, for my eyes and yours.

```
static const unsigned char qt_resource_name[] = {
  // images
    // cnctbtn_disconnected.png
    // cnctbtn_connected.png
    // cnctbtn_connecting.png
    // streambtn_start.png
    // d_logo_outlined.ico
    // d_logo_small.png
    // streambtn_stop.png
    // d_logo_small_outlined.png

};
```

Ideally there would be no build error, which I don't really understand since I can see and use the executable produced. If you need any other information, don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: `<file>images/d_logo_outlined.ico</file>` I don't see this file in the files that you listed that are in the images directory.

Comment: That's an error on my part, I just checked the images folder and everything is there. I just fixed the post to reflect that.